# NodeJS, how to handle refresh token for different devices/browsers

Tags: node.js, authentication, refresh-token

I'm building a nodeJS (express with mongoose) rest API which utilizes short life span **JWTs** and refresh tokens to keep the users logged-in. So far, I managed to create a system that creates and verifies both token types.

The issue that I'm facing right now is that, if someone logs in on a different device, it will generate a new **refresh token** for that user and they wouldn't be able to use the **refresh token** on the original device.

How can you determine from where the user logged in so that I can have different refresh tokens for each device?

Comment: Would the User-Agent header be sufficient?

Comment: @S.Dev Mhm.. I guess, but would that mean if the browser updates, it would change its version in the header. Also, wouldn't two identical computers have the same user-agent?

Comment: @Combustible Pizza Did you find a solution for this?